# SpringBatch JpaPagingItemReader SortOrder

Tags: spring-batch

I am using SpringBatch version 3.0.7, Hibernate 4.3.11, and H2 database. When using the JpaPagingItemReader, does the JPQL require a unique sort order? I see that it is required for the JdbcPagingItemReader (see [BATCH-2465](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2465)).

In a Step I am using a JpaPagingItemReader to load entities from the database and then write them to a flat file. I expect the flat file to contain unique entities sorted in the order specified by the JPQL. If I set the page size to something small, like 1, and then provide a JPQL statement that sorts entities with a non unique key, I am seeing the same entity repeat multiple times in the output file. If I sort by a unique key, there are no "duplicates". If I set the page size >= total number of entities, so there is only 1 page, there are no "duplicates".

Empirically it would seem that the JpaPagingItemReader requires the JPQL to have a unique sort key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a look at the implementation of JpaPagingItemReader, you'll find the method doReadPage():

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected void doReadPage() {

    EntityTransaction tx = null;

    if (transacted) {
        tx = entityManager.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();

        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.clear();
    }//end if

    Query query = createQuery().setFirstResult(getPage() * getPageSize()).setMaxResults(getPageSize());

    if (parameterValues != null) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> me : parameterValues.entrySet()) {
            query.setParameter(me.getKey(), me.getValue());
        }
    }

    if (results == null) {
        results = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<T>();
    }
    else {
        results.clear();
    }

    if (!transacted) {
        List<T> queryResult = query.getResultList();
        for (T entity : queryResult) {
            entityManager.detach(entity);
            results.add(entity);
        }//end if
    } else {
        results.addAll(query.getResultList());
        tx.commit();
    }//end if
}
```

As you can see, for every page that is read, an new query is created for every Page. Therefore, it must be ensured that your query returns always the **same amount** of elements in the **exact** same order, and hence, it needs a 'unique sort key'. Otherwise you will have duplicates and missing entries (there will be a missing entry for every duplicate, since the total number of rows will be identical).

Comment: This makes perfect sense. I was taking the implementation for granted. I had a mental picture of it executing a single query returning the whole result internally and then just giving back chunks of that when you call getPage(). Thank you for the explanation Hansjoerg.